# One header for multiple cpp-files

Tags: c++

Let's assume I have 3 cpp-files:

```
Main.cpp
First.cpp
Second.cpp
```

Now i want to use functions from First and Second in Main. Is there something to complain about, if I used only one header-file for both cpp-files and their functions?

Could there be any problems, when using the header-file in First, because I need a Function from Second in First?

Comment: For readability and style reasons you, generally speaking, want to keep groups of functionality separate across different header files. If `First` and `Second` do different things then you want to have those in different headers. The reason is because later on if you only want to use the functionality in `First` then you don't want to have to include what was in `Second` as well. If `First` and `Second` are always used together and do similar things then consider merging the 2 `cpp` files and then also merge the headers.

Comment: it is not clean style, but wont cause actual problems. header-files just gets 'pasted' in the source file, as the compiler sees it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As long as you follow the [ODR - One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) and every declaration is consistent, you will be fine.

Headers are usually meant to provide declarations for functions and other stuff, the linking phase (except when there's something a bit more involved like templates) will take care of resolving those dependencies.

I'm not saying anything on the design - not enough info provided.

Answer (score 3):

One header, Several Cpps. 
All Functions in Cpps can be declared in one header file. (Ex: "general.h")
And All Cpps should include the "general.h" file.
Then define bodies of declared functions.

Answer (score 1):

No, as long as you provide exactly one definition for each declaration to the compiler, it will be fine.

However it is a best practice to provide one source file per header file : if "First" need both, you just include First.h and Second.h

Answer (score 0):

As far as C++ goes, there won't be any issues with using one header file and splitting the actual implementations of the functions between 2 files. However this strays from convention, if you need functions from "Second.cpp" in "First.cpp" perhaps you should look at what is happening in each one and maybe the functionality should be separated into another file.

As personal preference I say you should stick to having one cpp file for each header file. Splitting the implementation is just going to cause headaches later if you need to refactor or move the implementation again.

Answer (score 0):

Just chiming in to say if you're using an architecture where you're mixing server and client code in one definition, have them separated by different cpp files may be the way to go.